# Weird Error 8 - Ghost Blog on Centos 6.4

Tags: linux, node.js, centos6, ghost-blog

When I first install and run Ghost via `npm start` all is well with the initial config.js settings.

After following several tutorials/questions, I still keep running into the `weird error 8` when I make any changes to the config.js

[Installing Ghost on Centos 6.4](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-centos-server-6-4/)

[Ghost Docs](http://docs.ghost.org/installation/linux/)

Any help/insight is much appreciated.

I have

- Reinstalled Ghost
- Restarted my Centos machine
- Tried with `--production` flag for npm start
- Tried editing the host/port in config to several options

**With initial config.js**

```
$ npm start --production

ghost@0.4.1 start /var/www/html/Projects/ghost.mydomain.name/ghost
node index

Ghost is running...
Your blog is now available on http://my-ghost-blog.com
Ctrl+C to shut down
^C
Ghost has shut down
Your blog is now offline
```

**Now changing config to 0.0.0.0 and port 80**

```
dev at centos64  /var/www/html/Projects/ghost.mydomain.name/ghost
$ npm start --production

ghost@0.4.1 start /var/www/html/Projects/ghost.mydomain.name/ghost
node index


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1135:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at process._tickFromSpinner (node.js:390:15)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your port 80 is being used by another program. try running this command on terminal to see who is the culprit:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

The last column indicates the name of the program. For example :

```
 0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1215/nginx
```

the culprit is `nginx`. Enter `kill 1215`to stop running the process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your port 80 might be in use by other process.

Have you got any web server running on that box?